# iOS CG dashed line path

Tags: ios, path, core-graphics, line

Drawing dashed line path like this is very simply

[image]

```
CGFloat lengths[] = { 12.0, 4.0, 12.0, 4.0,  4.0, 4.0 };
CGContextSetLineDash(ctx, 0, lengths, 6);
//... path code: moveTo, lineTo, strokePath
```

Is possible to draw more complicated dashed line?
Example:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've created a path with six lengths. Create another with 8 to represent just the end points of those wider segments:

```
CGFloat lengths[]  = { 12.0,           4.0, 12.0,          4.0,  4.0, 4.0 };
CGFloat lengths2[] = {  3.0, 6.0, 3.0, 4.0, 3.0, 6.0, 3.0, 12.0 };
```

So,  stroke the path twice, once with a narrow line width using `CGContextSetLineDash` of `lengths` and then again, a second time, with a thicker line width with `CGContextSetLineDash` of `lengths2`. For example, drawing this second one with a wider line width in red, it looks like:

[image]

If you draw both in black, it looks like:

[image]

Tweak the values as you see fit, but just make sure that the total of all of the `lengths` for both add up to the same value and so the stroked portions of `lengths2` line up with the start and end of the segments in `lengths`.